# How to make cex handle negative numbers?

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to make plots in R using the *text* command to display characters instead of points. Additionally, it is set up to use the log(10) of the number to scale the size of the plotted characters with *cex*. Unfortunately, numbers between 0 and 1 return negative log values, so *cex* appears to default to 1.

Is there a continuous way to get *cex* to use negative numbers, or should I switch to a different function?

Comment: Can you add 1 to your number before taking the log?

Comment: you could wrap the `log` output in `abs`

Comment: @jeremycg, that would be weird -- values <<1 would be plotted at very large character sizes.

Comment: @jeremycg-- I looked at that, but as Ben Bolker said it has the effect of making 0.001 and 1000 the same size.

Comment: @CactusWoman: Brilliant!